# How do I update DeletionPolicy from Retain to Delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have looked through a lot of CloudFormation documentations, but could not find any reference to update the `DeletionPolicy` from `Retain` to `Delete` for a resource in an already deployed stack.

The existing resource that is deployed in the stack has the `DeletionPolicy` set to `Retain`. I am unable to change it to `Delete`. When I try updating the stack with the deletionPolicy set to `Delete`, it says the `Change set did not include any changes to be deployed.`. But the change is obvious.

My intention is to get the deletionPolicy attribute removed from the resources in the stack or set them to `Delete`

Framework being used for deployments: [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com)

**Consider the below resource template as an existing resource in the stack:**

```js
  ResourceA:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    DeletionPolicy: Retain //This is how it is currently deployed
    Properties:
      RoleName: RoleName-${self:custom.env.stage}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: events.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
```

**Trying to get the above resource properties changed to:**

```js
  ResourceA:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    DeletionPolicy: Delete // <--- The change
    Properties:
      RoleName: RoleName-${self:custom.env.stage}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: events.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
```

**The intention is to get rid of the deletion policy, but having the deletionPolicy as Delete would also allow me to continue with what I am intending to do.**

```js
  ResourceA:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: RoleName-${self:custom.env.stage}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: events.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
```

Comment: Did you actually try to change it and update the stack?

Comment: I am trying to update the stack. The already deployed stack has the deletionPolicy as retain.

Comment: So why not change to to retain in the template? I'm not sure what is your issue.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, the existing policy is already set to retain. I need to change that to delete, and I am unable to do that. When I try updating the stack with the deletionPolicy set to delete, it says the deployment will be skipped because no changes were found in the stack template. But note that the existing stack template on CloudFormation has the deletionPolicy set to Retain, and the stack that is being deployed has the DeletionPolicy as Delete. The different is obvious. No idea why CF is not seeing the difference and deploying it.

Comment: Can you please provide example template demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @Marcin, I have added an example template. Please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: I run your example. There is absolutely no problem with changing the `DeletionPolicy`. Everything works as expected.  But I use valina CloudFormation. You seem to be using serverless framewrok? If yes, that this is serverless issue, not CloudFormation.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, not sure if its a serverless issue or I might be wrong. Because I can see that serverless is packaging and forming the cloud formation template with the deletionPolicy set to delete. When the template is sent to cloud formation, cf compares it with the existing template it has and returns that there are no changes to the template. Not sure why this is happening even though there is an obvious difference in the deletionPolicy :(

Comment: Changeset is far from perfect. Can you just run the actual update of the stack?

Comment: @Marcin, unfortunately, I cannot do that. our deployment pipelines are set up in such a way that it is not possible to deploy any other way.

Comment: Then you can't change the deletionpolicy.

Comment: I was able to update the DeletionPolicy by updating the stack through the Cloudformation console and uploading a new template file. How are you changing the template? (e.g. in code or find and replace in the template file)

Answer (score 1):

@Gaurav: I had the same issue using the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/). Just updating the `DeletionPolicy` resulted in a skipped update.

The workaround for me was to add a dummy resource to the stack to get the update deployed, then remove the dummy resource and deploy again.

Looks like a bug in Serverless Framework.

Answer (score 0):

This the expected behaviour of `Retain` as explained in AWS docs

```
To keep a resource when its stack is deleted, specify Retain for that resource. You can use retain for any resource. For example, you can retain a nested stack, Amazon S3 bucket, or EC2 instance so that you can continue to use or modify those resources after you delete their stacks.
```

Apply some subsequent changes to see make sure it is applied

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html